# BulletPHP REST API and NGINX in subfolder

Tags: php, rest, nginx

I'm trying to set up BulletPHP with NGINX in a subfolder.

- BulletPHP is in `domain.de/mi/sp/bullet/`
- my main script is in `domain.de/mi/sp/esa2/index.php`
- and the REST api should be accessable on `domain.de/mi/sp/esa2/api`

When I call http://domain.de/mi/sp/esa2/api/ I get "Not Found" from BulletPHP. But why?

This is the NGINX configuration for this path:

```
 location ~ ^/mi/sp/esa2/api {
     try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ /mi/sp/esa2/index.php$is_args?u=$args;
 }
```

This is the index.php script:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../bullet/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Bullet\App();
// I also tried '/' here...
$app->path('/mi/sp/esa2/api/', function($request) {
    return "Hello World!";
});

echo $app->run(new Bullet\Request());

?>
```

Comment: Well it's just a guess, cause I'm not that familiar with nginx yet, but you're using a trailing `/` in PHP and URL, but a non-trailing slash in `location ~ ^/mi/sp/esa2/api` (no slash `/` behind api). Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a few issues with your configuration.

You have chosen to use a regex `location` for what is essentially a prefix. It probably doesn't break anything, but regex locations have a different execution order to prefix locations, so you should be aware. Also, prefix locations are more efficient. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

You use the `$request_uri` which is set once at the start of request processing, and also includes the query string. It is more usual to construct `try_files` URIs from the `$uri` variable which contains the current URI (after internal transformations). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Your default action is:

```
/mi/sp/esa2/index.php$is_args?u=$args
```

For no query string, you will get:

```
/mi/sp/esa2/index.php?u=
```

With a query string (say: xxx), you will get:

```
    /mi/sp/esa2/index.php??u=xxx
```

So you should delete the `$is_arg` as it is just adding a second `?` to the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_is_args) for details.

You might want to substitute your `index.php` file for:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

just to check that you are passing the correct parameters to your framework.